# What is this Textmate keyboard shortcut doing (Control+Shift+.)

Tags: textmate

It's inserting `<%=  %>` into my HTML, but what is that for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP-style short form tags for PHP scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It's also used in ERB which is the ruby template engine and is used as the default template engine in Ruby on Rails.

ERB docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html
Rails use of ERB: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html